# An invalid character [34] was present in the Cookie value Java cookie

Tags: java, cookie

Создаю `Cookie` в `JavaEE`. Передаю `JSONObject` и делаю преобразование в строку (`.toJSONString`).

Выводит такую штуку: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An invalid character [34] was present in the Cookie value`

Java 8, IDEA 2016 2.

Comment: что находится в Cookie?

Comment: @Komdosh объект `json` - `{"dontRemember":false,"id":1,"categories":"unlock","hash":"0ab8c0e0cbc7ae1bce28d8b03c1b75b7"}`

Comment: хм, вроде всё в порядке, но ошибка, как я понимаю, говорит о том, что на 34 позиции неподдерживаемый символ. Может там буква e русская?

Comment: @Komdosh точно не русская.

Comment: @Komdosh Решил проблему.

Comment: напишите как, интересно.

Comment: @Komdosh написал.

Answer (score 1):

Для создания:

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie(name, URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8"));
```

Для чтения:

```
String value = URLDecoder.decode(cookie.getValue(), "UTF-8");
```

Взято [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109318/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-control-character-in-cookie-value-or-attribu)